# Unable to connect to localhost because of error: Apache 403 Forbidden

Tags: apache

I am unable to connect my localhost due to this error:

> 403 Forbidden 
>   You don't have permission to access / on this server.Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80.

Directory/file permissions are correct. I can't re-install LAMP.

Error log:

```
[ 2015-10-10 16:47:49.9040 1544/7f04622e1740 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:650 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.1540/generation-0/request
[ 2015-10-10 16:47:49.9755 1551/7f726a632780 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:321 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.1540/generation-0/logging
[ 2015-10-10 16:47:49.9757 1541/7f2c5a707740 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:728 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
[ 2015-10-10 16:47:49.0050 1564/7fb0c6514740 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:538 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'nobody', 'default_group' => 'www-data', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/usr/bin/ruby', 'default_user' => 'www-data', 'log_level' => '0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini', 'passenger_version' => '4.0.53', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'true', 'web_server_passenger_version' => '4.0.53', 'web_server_pid' => '1561', 'web_server_type' => 'apache', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '33', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '33' }
[ 2015-10-10 16:47:50.0093 1567/7fd3f8434740 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:650 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.1561/generation-0/request
[ 2015-10-10 16:47:50.0195 1575/7febe24c9780 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:321 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.1561/generation-0/logging
[ 2015-10-10 16:47:50.0197 1564/7fb0c6514740 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:728 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
[Sat Oct 10 16:47:55.529424 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1561] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/4.0.53 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Oct 10 16:47:55.534042 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1561] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Oct 10 16:50:16.578930 2015] [core:error] [pid 1621] (13)Permission denied: [client ::1:49447] AH00035: access to /test.php denied (filesystem path '/var/www/html') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path, referer: http://localhost/
[Sat Oct 10 16:50:17.689444 2015] [core:error] [pid 1621] (13)Permission denied: [client ::1:49447] AH00035: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/var/www/html') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path, referer: http://localhost/test.php
```

Comment: Well, like the error says, your permissions are wrong. Check them. Google Wordpress permissions and you'll find countless resources explaining this.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply, but I tried ' chmod -R 0664 /var/www ' and even '-R 777', but still didn't get access to localhost.

Comment: I'd suggest you try the steps on this page and, if it still doesn't work, edit your question to include the output of the various commands there. https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied

Comment: Problem had been sorted out. Thanks to Ed Cottrell.